# Isolated DC DC converter operating principle

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm doing a course project on electrical engineering subject. I have to use this specific DC DC converter [ISL2412 XP Power DC DC converter](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/xp-power/ISL2412/1470-1556-5-ND/4487937). But before I can use it, I have to explain how does it work.

I can't find anything about it's operating principle. The only thing I found out is that it isolated type. So this type of DC DC converters has galvanic isolation, is that the main part of it that do voltage transform?

So the question is, what is the isolated DC DC converter operating principle?

Comment: You are *literally* buying a black box with these parts. I can make an educated guess as to *which* topology it uses, but without reverse engineering it will be difficult.

Comment: @W5VO  Russian school of experimentalism [I say with pride].

Comment: It could be an isolated [flyback converter](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen4517/materials/flyback.pdf) with an inductor-transformer. It could be a transformer-based isolated converter. Perhaps a forward converter, or a [push-pull converter](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu34.php).

Comment: How it **does** work is up to the manufacturer. But, many ways it MIGHT work can bne seen [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?biw=1745&bih=977&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=isolated+dc+dc+converter&oq=isolated+dc+dc+converter&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24l6.173886.180740.0.182092.26.24.1.0.0.0.344.3642.2-13j1.14.0....0...1c.1.64.img..11.15.3643...0i30j0i10i24.Fr1jQOYoNvw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may not apply to the specific device from XP Power, application note [slyt211](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt211/slyt211.pdf) from Texas Instruments explains how small (<5W) isolated power converters such as the [DCP010512](http://www.ti.com/product/DCP010512B) operate. Essentially, inside the converter, there is a set of switches and an isolation power transformer. The controller generates a waveform that allows for power to be rectified on the isolated side. An *unregulated* device has an internal diagram such as:

[image: Texas Instruments Functional Block Diagram for DCP010512B]

However, the ISL2412 you wish to use has regulated outputs. This adds additional complexity to the device. The [LTM8048 datasheet](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8048fg.pdf) shows how such a regulator could be implemented, along with the other switching electronics:

[image: LTM8048 block diagram from page 8 of https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8048fg.pdf]

For dual-supply operation, Murata's [BEI15 Series](http://power.murata.com/data/power/bei15.pdf) includes a block diagram for regulated outputs:

[image: BEI15 Series connection diagram from page 1 of http://power.murata.com/data/power/bei15.pdf]

Further, Digikey reveals that this BEI15 Series module is not encapsulated, allowing you to see how components are arranged:

[image: BEI15 Series module image from https://media.digikey.com/photos/Murata%20Photos/MFG_BEI15-Series.jpg]

Here, you can see the control IC on the load side in the front-left of the module, the board-level transformer in the middle of the board with a snap-in ferrite core with the Murata logo, and two switching devices along with ceramic capacitors on the far edge of the device.

Finally, the Murata [BWR Series](http://power.murata.com/data/power/bwr33w.pdf) devices includes a nearly complete diagram of a higher power (ca. 30W) isolated converter using synchronous rectification on the load side:

[image: BWR Series simplified schematic from page 1 of http://power.murata.com/data/power/bwr33w.pdf]

Additional references:

- The [DFC10 Series](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Power%20One%20PDFs/DFC10U24D12.pdf) from Power One has a block diagram on page 48
- This [image](https://media.digikey.com/photos/GE%20Critical%20Power%20Photos/SHHN000A3CL41Z.JPG) of a SHHN000A3 Series converter from GE on Digikey
- The [DSP1 Series](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Power%20One%20PDFs/DSP1%20Series%20%28Dual%20Output%29.pdf) from Power One has a block diagram on page 2
- This [image](https://media.digikey.com/photos/Texas%20Instr%20Photos/ptb48511aah.JPG) of a PTB48510 converter from TI on Digikey
- The [IMX70, IMY70 Series](http://belpowersolutions.com/sites/belpowersolutions.com/files/documents/power/datasheet/bcd.00002_ah_imx_imy70.pdf) from BEL has two block diagrams on page 3